# How to format SQL code in SequelPro locally?

Tags: sequelpro

In SequelPro, there's a built in SQL format bundle. This bundle using a web based SQL format API, hence it requires internet connection. Is there a solution to format code locally?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some script for format SQL like `sqlparse`.
There are some examples in [related issue](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/1988).